# Want to get standard output or error when using Process

Tags: java

I want to use `"which hoge"` for obtaining a path for the hoge in Java code.

when "hoge" exists, the path can be obtained by `Process#getInputStream.`

but when "hoge" doesn't exist, both input stream and error stream from `Process#get(Input|Error)Stream`s give `"null"`.

but in terminal (OS X), if I try "which unexists", I get "unexists not found".

where does the message "unexists not found" go? How can I get this?

Does Java use another "which"?

Comment: I think you may need to execute the command via a shell

Answer (score 1):

Your shell probably has "which" as a built-in command, so it doesn't use the /bin/which program. There are likely many differences between the two. You can check which which you use with the command "type which" and use the program instead of the built-in command using /bin/which.

From Java, you can know if a result was found by checking the process exit status returned by Process.waitFor(). If the status is 0 which found a match, if non-zero it didn't or there was some other error.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. "which" on terminal is a built-in command.

Comment: and which used by Java is /usr/bin/which which doesn't say anything when hove doesn't exist.